# Как уменьшить размер сборки react приложения? Как подключать скрипты по востребованию?

Tags: reactjs, redux, spa

Пишу спа приложение на реакт.
У меня дев сборка 5.6mb, продакшн сборка 1.7 и приложение ещё будет дописываться. Какой размер считается оптимальным, как можно уменьшить?

Можно ли как-то подгружать нужные библиотеки по востребованию на конкретных страницах. Например есть экран который рисует графики, я не хочу тянуть этот функционал во всю сборку, можно ли как-то подгружать такие библиотеки по востребованию? Надеюсь меня поняли, спасибо.

Comment: в доках вебпака про это есть

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/

Comment: То что нужно спасибо

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Comment: Приказы пусть холопы исполняют!